# Hide UISearchDisplayController of UITableView initially ( iOS SDK )?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I hide UISearchDisplayController of UITableView initially ? I just want user to scroll up to see the UISearchBar.

UPDATE: I am thinking of scrolling the UITableView 40px lower, so that the UISearchBar can be "hidden" from user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution is in `viewWillAppear:animted` :

```
[my_table_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, searchController.searchBar.bounds.size.height)];
```

**UPDATE** we should obtain the height of `UISearchBar` instead of using fixed values.

Comment: height of SearchBar is 44 points

Comment: Don't use constants like this. Use `searchController.searchBar.bounds.height` instead. The height may change in future iOS versions and that will break your code, but not this one.

Comment: correct. Didn't aware this 5 years ago. thanks.

Comment: `searchController.searchBar.bounds.height` property doesn't exist. It should be `searchController.searchBar.bounds.size.height`

Comment: You're right. corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I hide search bar in view will appear. This snipped will make sure that search bar is initially hidden only at the very first time of view will appear call.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //hide search bar
    if (_searchBarRevealed == NO) {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);
        _searchBarRevealed = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `TAToolbarHeight()` ? I assume it returns the value of `44` ?

Comment: yes, sorry its my internal fuction